# Protecting Wordpress Blog

Tags: security, wordpress

I have an independent site and I am using Wordpress as Content Management System for that. My site has been hacked two times now. Pardon me, am a newbie, but can anyone guide me to how to protect it from being hacked? I will be really thankful.

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting? If so make sure that the hosting itself hacked or not. May be it is not your site's fault.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links, maybe they are helpful for you:

- http://www.mastermindblogger.com/2011/14-ways-to-prevent-your-wordpress-blog-from-being-hacked/
- http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/how-to-stop-your-wordpress-blog-getting-hacked
- http://getinternetmarketingstrategies.com/2010/04/how-to-secure-wordpress-blogs-prevent-the-hacking-of-your-blog/
- http://blogcritics.org/scitech/article/10-tips-to-make-wordpress-hack/
- http://tek3d.org/how-to-protect-wordpress-blog-from-hacks

There is also a plugin, which backups your wordpress data into your dropbox account !

But you could specify what you understand by hacked ? Got it deleted, spam comments ?

Comment: no, someone just actually posted a page that I got hacked. I think it was SQL Injection I guess.

Comment: okay, are you using the newest version of wordpress ?

Comment: yes I used the newest version of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links , check it out.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/security-plugins-wordpress-bulletproof/
- http://designmodo.com/wordpress-security-plugins/

And also keep ASKIMAT plugin activate , it saves your wordpress site from spam e-mails.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new kid on the block but the are getting some impressive reviews.

cloudsafe365.com - a free wp plugin that prevents hacking and content scrape.

Apparently they even clean you dirty dishes.

Answer (score 0):

- Insure correct File and Directory permissions.
- No 'admin' user
- Refresh auth and salt values in wp-config
- Use complex passwords
- If you did not completely remove (or rename) your old site directories, you may be leaving the hacker's backdoor intact.
- Completely delete any unused plugin and theme directories.
- Check your web access logs for hackers fishing for exploits.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Security is mandatory for every websites, you can try this following ways for strong protection

1. Disable file browsing via .htaccess file
2. Use plugins like **limit login attempts** especially this is for limit brute force login attempts. You can completely kick off brute force logins by changing WordPress login url
3. Always up to date with WordPress and plugins
4. Don't use poor coded plugins or themes.
5. Use plugins like securi for monitoring whole site from malware.
6. Don't use pirated themes or plugins
7. Tons of security plugins available on WordPress plugins repository for every security vulnerabilities problems.